# How to produce a string of double-quote with emacs lisp?

Tags: string, elisp

I need to produce a string with emacs lisp, in which, there must contain double-quote '"'. By studying the string syntax of emacs lisp, I thought "\"" would represent such double-quote. But to my surprise, I the following expression 
(concat "\"")
produced 
"\""
the '\' being not desired.

Please teach me how I can produce a pure double quote in a string?

Thanks in advance.

Yu

Comment: This is sort of an unusual comment but...I don't think this question needs to be community wiki. It is a fairly specific question, programming related, and has a definite set of correct answers. When you mark something as community wiki, you don't get any reputation points when someone votes it up. So, only put community wiki when the question is an opinion poll, or doesn't have any clear cut answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing the output in the minibuffer, correct?

There isn't a '\' in the string data.  Note the function result in the minibuffer is surrounded by quotes.  It is showing you a representation of the string, not just its data.

To show *you* that the quote inside is part of the data and not a terminator for the string, it escapes the contained quote when printing it.

Try (insert "\"").  This will print the value of the string at the current location of the mark, which will be just the quote mark.

Answer (score 1):

The expression of 
(concat "\"") would produce the expected result of single double-quote '"'.

I was confused with the evaluation result in interactive emacs-lisp buffer, which uses emacs-lisp's string representation syntax. In which, a double-quote is represented as "\"".

In the actual execution, it would yield the correct result of a double-quote.

Sorry for the trouble!

Yu Shen